# Shell Navigation xamarinForms .net Maui

Tags: xamarin, maui

i try to make a simple navigation using a button from a page to another page inside my maui app but the navigation not working. i register the route inside my appShell.cs:

`Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(LoadingQuiz),typeof(LoadingQuiz));`

and inside my view model i implement the navigation method like this :

```cs
[QueryProperty(nameof(QuizJson), nameof(QuizesVM))]
    public partial class QuizDetailsViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        //Navigation
        //   [RelayCommand]
        //  public Task Navigate() => Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(LoadingQuiz));

         [RelayCommand]
         public async Task NavigateToAsync() {
             await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(LoadingQuiz));
         }
        
        private string quizJson;
        public string QuizJson
        {

            get { return quizJson; }
            set
            {
                quizJson = value;
                QuizesVM = Helpers.Helpers.DeserializeObject<QuizVM>(quizJson);
            }
        }
        private QuizVM quizvm;
        public QuizVM QuizesVM
        {
            get { return quizvm; }
            set
            {
                quizvm = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(QuizesVM));
            }

        }
        public QuizDetailsViewModel()
        {
          
        }

    }
```

and i bind it inside my view :

```xml
<Button Text=" Start Quiz" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#A8A223" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="50" CornerRadius="25" HorizontalOptions="Center" Command="{Binding NavigateToCommand}"/>
```

This is my QuizHomeDetails.cs where i make the binding between the view and viewmodel :

```xml
public partial class QuizHomeDetails : ContentPage
{
    public QuizHomeDetails(QuizDetailsViewModel vm)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = vm;
        //Run the method in seperat thread 
        Task.Run(Rotateimage);
    }

    private async void Rotateimage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await QuizImg.RelRotateTo(360, 5000, Easing.BounceOut);

        }
    }


}
```

Also i registered the pages and the viewmodels in my program file and the navigation still not working when i click on the button

Comment: The command name should be `NavigateToAsyncCommand`

Comment: @Paramjit This is actually wrong. CommunityToolkit.MVVM knows to generate IAsyncRelayCommand, and skips the word Async in the command name.

Comment: If you want any help, you will need to provide much more code. Starting with the constructor of the page. The view model class, and the page xaml.

Comment: i updated the post bro by the way when i hover on the NavigateToCommand it return the type IAsyncRelayCommand but when i click nothing happen

Comment: 1.When running the program, set the breakpoint at `await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(LoadingQuiz));`, see if it can get there if clicking the button.2. Make sure you set the binding with View and ViewModel. As I tested your code, it can navigate as expected.

Comment: I make the breakpoint on the await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(LoadingQuiz)) but it can't get there if i click the button and for the binding for the view and viewmodel i make it correctly . i don't understand why it's not working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the sample code below on how to use a button to navigate from `MainPage` to `LoadingQuiz` page.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Button Text=" Start Quiz" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#A8A223" WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="50" CornerRadius="25" HorizontalOptions="Center" Command="{Binding NavigateToCommand}"/>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
public MainPage(MainPageViewModel vm) 
{
     InitializeComponent();

     BindingContext= vm;
}
```

**MainPageViewMode.cs**

```
public partial class MainPageViewModel 
{

     [RelayCommand]
     public async Task NavigateToAsync()
     {

          await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(LoadingQuiz));
     }
}
```

Comment: it does not working for me i don't understand where is the issue ?

Comment: @montassarmeddeb That's weird, could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) via github repo link?

Comment: Hey Bro i found the error : when i change the place of the button it work so the problem was that the button was inside a stacklayout in a second row and the height of that row was not enough so when i click on the button nothing happen and it can even access to it so i put her in a third row and it work

Comment: @montassarmeddeb Good job Bro!  So the button needs enough height to get it working. Gald to see it worked finally!

Comment: No worries, Bro, feel free to reach out if you got any questions.